# Extend mocha.d.ts with IEventEmitter from node.d.ts

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

In my `.ts` code, I have `mocha.run().on('start', () => {})` but it is underlined since typescript uses mocha.d.ts which does not recognise that IRunner [extends](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L94) Node's EventEmitter. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

just do `interface IRunner extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {}` in the mocha.d.ts file